# How to include column in against parameter for a match against query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match, against

I have a table of keywords that I need to match against another table of data and get the counts for the keywords that matched. Since the "against" parameter in the match against query does not take columns, only literal strings, is there any way to have the following query work?

```
  SELECT tbl.kw_keyword, COUNT(*) FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM data a, keywords b WHERE MATCH(a.dd_text)
   AGAINST (b.kw_keyword)) AS tbl;
```

Comment: The `AGAINST` parameter can be any expression.

Comment: Yes but i need it to be the data from the keywords column. In this case, if I execute the above query, I get the following error: Error Code: 1210
Incorrect arguments to AGAINST

Comment: Do you have a full-text index on that column?

Comment: Yes i have created a full text index on the dd_text column in the data table

Comment: Ah, right, the doc says _The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row._.

Comment: I think you need to use dynamically-generated SQL to get around that restriction.

Comment: @Barmar, that's correct, you should just post that as an answer.

Comment: Can you please explain what is dynamically-generated SQL and how to generate it.. sorry i just started using mysql

Comment: @BillKarwin It's not really an answer unless I actually show how to do it, and I don't have the time to write it now. The OP should google it and learn.

Comment: @Barmar, point taken, you're right a good answer should be complete. I agree that people who ask questions like this as raw beginners should do some self-study first, and read a tutorial or a book or about 50,000 previous StackOverflow questions that answer the basics.

Comment: You can search SO for the tags `[mysql] [dynamic-sql]`